# Is there a trigger function for updating a field when a timestamp field is in the past?

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have got a table in PostgreSQL with a column 'status' (character varying) and a column 'timestamp' (timestamp without time zone).

Now I want to automatically update the status column as soon as the timestamp field is in the past. Therefore I am looking for a trigger function (or something else?), which compares as soon as the current date changes (00:00 each day) the current date with all the timestamps in the table and changes the status field if needed.

Is it possible to solve that use case by trigger functions whithin the table or should I outsource the comparision to a software like e.g. FME?

Comment: I think that this is a bad idea. Leave the data just as they are, and calculate the status when you query the data.

Comment: Good point, but I need to use the data in several applications, so I wanted to avoid the implementation of the conditional statements in every application by calculating the status directly in the database

Comment: What about a materialized view that is refreshed every day?

Comment: I will give it a try!

Comment: Thank you, first I used a materialized view until I realized, that I had to be able to edit the data. Now I am using a pg_agent job, which updates every day the hole table and compares the actual date with the given timestamp. That solution works for me.

Comment: @pascatl how did you solve it? do you have any snippets?